# Can't get JLabel to shift on GUI from scratch

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, layout-manager

I'm learning the basics of GUI for a small hobby project and have been learning to code one from scratch. I have the initial setups and variables and such, but I'm having as issue. I can't seem to get my JLabel clas to shift to the left side of the panel. I understand there are easier ways to code a GUI. I am simply going for the most basic of basic declarations for a GUI. Here is my code:

```
public class GUIGameFromScratch {
static String[] Classes = {
            "Barbarian",
            "Fighter",
            "Rogue",
            "Wizard"
        };
static String[] Races = {
            "Dwarf",
            "Gnome",
            "Half-Orc",
            "Human"
        };
static String[] Gender = {
            "Male",
            "Female"
        };
static String cls;
static String rcs;
static String gen;
static String gameName = "RPG Text";
static Component frame = null;
static Component icon = null;

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Classes(Classes);
    Races(Races);
    Gender(Gender);
    JFrame display = new JFrame();
    display.setSize(300,250);
    display.setVisible(true);
    display.setTitle(gameName);
    display.setResizable(false);
    JPanel disPane = new JPanel();
    display.add(disPane);
    disPane.setVisible(true);
    disPane.setSize(295,245);
    JLabel clas = new JLabel();
    disPane.add(clas);
    clas.setVisible(true);
    clas.setLocation(5,5);
    clas.setSize(100,50);
    clas.setText("Class: " + cls);
}

public static void Classes(String[] Classes){
    cls = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame,
            "Choose a Class:",
            gameName,
            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, (Icon) icon,
            Classes,
            Classes[0]
    );
}

public static void Races(String[] Races){
    rcs = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame,
            "Choose a Race:",
            gameName,
            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, (Icon) icon,
            Races,
            Races[0]
    );
}

public static void Gender(String[] Gender){
    gen = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame,
            "Choose a Gender:",
            gameName,
            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, (Icon) icon,
            Gender,
            Gender[0]
    );
}
}
```

I'm not entirely sure how to get around this issue. I need to be able to shift the labels to flush out my GUI, but nothing seems to work. I've tried location, locale, horizontal alignment, etc. There must be some function I am missing that I haven't been able to find yet. Once again, I understand that I am taking a very strict approach to this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you need to use layout for that. Try this for your frame object display.setLayout(new FlowLayout((FlowLayout.LEFT)));

Answer (score 2):

Swing/AWT displays child components using layout managers.  Every container (such as a JPanel) has a layout manager.

A layout manager’s job is to set the location and size of each child component.  Any values you pass when you call `setLocation` will be discarded when the parent’s layout manager lays out its children and determines what their locations and sizes should be.

The easiest solution is to specify a layout manager that places its child components on the left side:

```
JPanel disPane = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
```

I’m sure you plan to have more components in the window.  If you want them laid out in a more complex way, you may need a more complex layout manager, or a combination of many layout managers.  It is very common to use many JPanels inside one another, each with its own layout manager.  For instance, if you need a row of identically sized buttons, you might use a [GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html) for a separate JPanel containing just those buttons.

It’s useful to browse the documentation to see which layout managers are available:

- The [documentation of LayoutManager itself](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/LayoutManager.html) has an “All Known Implementing Classes” section near the top of the page.
- The [documentation of the java.awt package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/package-summary.html) and the [documentation of the javax.swing package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html) include some standard layout managers, all of whose names end with `Layout`.

The most useful layout manager, in my opinion, is [GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html) (not to be confused with GridLayout).  It is hard to learn, largely because laying out components can be a complex problem, but once you fully understand it, it becomes extremely useful and surprisingly easy to work with.

Some other commonly used layouts are:

- [BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html)
- [GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html)
- [CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html)

But no single layout manager can solve all problems, which is why programmers are expected to combine and nest them.

### Sizing

Just as the layout manager controls the locations of child components, it can also control their sizes.

You are currently setting your JLabel’s size to 100×50 pixels.  I’m sure it looks fine on your computer.

But Java is designed to run on many computers and many operating systems.  If your JLabel’s font is 12 point Lucida, how many pixels high does the JLabel need to be?  A “12 point” font is not 12 pixels high;  12 points is actually <sup>12</sup>⁄<sub>72</sub> inch.  Exactly how many pixels are needed to correspond to that measurement depends on the user’s monitor and the current graphics resolution.

In theory, you could do all the math yourself to determine how large your JLabel needs to be, but you don’t need to, because Swing already does it.  The JLabel’s [preferred size](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getPreferredSize()) already accounts for that.

Simply do not set your JLabel’s size at all, and the parent layout manager will respect its default preferred size, no matter what size may be appropriate on the computer where the program is running.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest starting [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to look at some of the foundational layout systems available in Swing. Generally you want to assign a layout manager to your JFrame and then use the layout manager to locate components in the window. Another note I'd make is to avoid setting your components or the JFrame visible before you have finished setting all of its parameters like sizes or titles because it could theoretically present the changes to the user live.